# Button in form not detected in PHP

Tags: php

I am using a HTML form as Below.

```
<form name="frmUploadFile" id="frmUploadFile" action="file1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="flUpload" id="flUpload"/>
  <input type="button" name="btnButton" id="btnButton" value="Button Form"/>      
</form>
```

When I submit the form the button is not getting detected in PHP Post Method. But when I replace the input type="submit" the submit is getting detected and its value getting displayed.

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['btnButton']))
{
  $File = $_FILES['flUpload'];

  print "File Name : ".$File['name'];
  exit(); 
}
```

I am submitting form by the following jquery

```
$('#btnButton').click(function(){
  $('#frmUploadFile').submit(); 
});
```

The above doesn't works.Despite button being a form element why button is not detected in php

Comment: buttons have their own tag: `<button>`

Comment: In addition, an `<input type="button">` won't submit a form. They're only there so you can catch them in JS.

Comment: What happens whenb you do a `print_r($_REQUEST);`?

Comment: I am submitting form through jquery

Comment: Use submit type element or add on click event to submit form to your current button element

Comment: check this link 

[submitting-a-form-using-input-type-button][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694608/submitting-a-form-using-input-type-button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only "successful" form controls will be submitted in form data. An `<input type="button">` can never be successful as it exists solely to have JavaScript bound to it.

If you replace it with `type="submit"` **and** use it to submit the form (and not override it with JavaScript), then the data will appear.

---

Update in response to comments:

> I am submitting form through jquery

You are therefore either calling the `submit()` method of the form (which won't make any button successful) or you are using Ajax (in which case you might not be submitting the file either).

In either case, the button won't form part of the data, so don't use it to determine if the form was submitted. Check to see if the file is in the data, or if the method used to make the request was *post*.

---

As an aside, don't use `<input type="button">` + JS to submit forms. Instead, follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Use a regular submit button, then enhance it with JavaScript.

---

Further update in response to edits:

Your JavaScript isn't doing anything that a submit button wouldn't do. Use `type="submit"` and delete the JS entirely.