# HTML Form Submission Issues

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm working on a basic landing page with a one-field form. It's my first foray into forms so forgive me if this is basic or obvious.

Here's the code for the form:

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Thank you - we'll send an invite soon.')">
    <p><label for="email">ENTER YOUR EMAIL: </label><input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input name="Submit" type="button" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

As you can see, it's pretty basic. However, the submit button doesn't work; you have to press enter to submit the form. On top of that, I can't get the onsubmit alert to work either. I've tried a thousand different configurations with minimal success, and I'm at the end of my rope.

Comment: Single quote in the javascript string will also cause some issues... we'll

Comment: change your `type="button"` into `type="submit"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submitting a form using <input type ="button">](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694608/submitting-a-form-using-input-type-button)

Answer (score 3):

Change the button type to submit

```
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the Button type to submit and also fix your Javascript, you have an extra apostrophe:

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="alert('Thank you - we will send an invite soon.');">
    <p><label for="email">ENTER YOUR EMAIL: </label><input type="email" id="email" name="email"/>
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: You can simply escape the apostrophe with a backslash if you like.

Answer (score 2):

`type="button"` isn't a submit button. It's a "does nothing" button that you can hang JavaScript from.

You are looking for `type="submit"`.

Answer (score -2):

Since You want to submit a form you mast use `input type = submit` . For example:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

You can also use

```
<button type="submit"> Submit </button>
```