# Form image submit not detected

Tags: php, html, image, forms

Can someone please spot what I am doing wrong? I copied this over from a different page on my site where it works but I can't get it to work on this one. There are text inputs also that I have left out that are working as expected. Thanks.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {

    if (isset($_POST['pic'])){
        //isset never detected when image is uploaded in html
    }

}


<html>
<form class="form-horizontal" onsubmit="return checkSize(2097152)" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-toggle="validator" method="POST" action="profile.php">
<input id="pic" name="pic" type="file" accept="image/*" class="text-center center-block well well-sm">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save">Save Changes</button>
                <a href="profile.php" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

//check image size func
function checkSize(max_img_size)
{
    var input = document.getElementById("pic");
    // check for browser support (may need to be modified)
    if(input.files && input.files.length == 1)
    {           
        if (input.files[0].size > max_img_size) 
        {
            alert("Profile Picture must be less than " + (max_img_size/1024/1024) + "MB");
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Addition: I just did a print_r($_POST); print_r($_FILES); and got without a picture being uploaded:

Array ( [nickname] => raySirSharp [motto] => Big gulps eh? [email] => razer88@hotmail.com [submit] => ) Array ( [pic] => Array ( [name] => [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 4 [size] => 0 ) )

With a picture uploaded:

Array ( [nickname] => raySirSharp [motto] => Big gulps eh? [email] => razer88@hotmail.com [submit] => ) Array ( [pic] => Array ( [name] => 12472627_211490652554223_5803523050459466916_n.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpvNCBzj [error] => 0 [size] => 70254 ) )

What can I use to detect if a picture has been uploaded or not?

I tried:

```
if (isset($_FILES['pic'])){ //always true :( }
```

Comment: What is that checkSize() function in onsubmit?

Comment: Hey @Ryan please add java script function codes to your answer

Comment: Is your PHP tag closed? File is saved as a PHP file? Js sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ryan You are using $_POST while your input type is **file** 
Try using `$_FILES['pic']` instead of $_POST

Answer (score 1):

empty instead of isset

```
if (!empty($_POST['pic'])){

}
```

i hope it will solve your issue

one more thing that i didnt find anycode for submitting form so without submit you can't get the POST variables on next page.

Answer (score 1):

To accept a file from a HTML form you need to use the $_FILES instead of the $_POST. For example you can use `$_FILES["pic"]["name"]` to get the file name.

From there you can move the picture to a new location like this:
`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], "/var/tmp/pic.jpg")`

More info is available at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: This did the trick just changed the POST to (isset($_FILES["pic"])). Except now it always recognizes something as being submitted even if the input is empty..

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

```
if (!empty($_FILES["pic"]["name"])){ }
```

Works! :)

Answer (score 0):

Include `type='submit'` in your button.

```
<button type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save">
  Save Changes
</button>
```

> To submit the `<form>` your input type needs to be `submit`.

The HTML Submit button is used to submit form data to the script mentioned in the ACTION attribute. As long as SUBMIT has an ACTION set, then your data will get sent somewhere. But the NAME attribute of the Submit buttons comes in very handy. You can use this Name to test if the form was really submitted, or if the user just clicked the refresh button. This is important when the PHP script is on the same page as the HTML form.

For more info, please [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694608/submitting-a-form-using-input-type-button) or [PHP and the Submit Button of HTML Forms](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p5.html)

Comment: I think maybe you are onto something because the page I already have a similar form like this submits to a seperate page, but I tried to include type = submit and nothing changed.

Comment: As far my understanding is, `<form>` will not get submitted without `type='submit'`, unless submission is being handled through `AJAX` @RyanClaxton

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print_r($_POST);
```

to see results, if not returning anything maybe is the problem is checkSize() trigger by onsubmit...

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have not closed your `php` `tag` before `html` start. And try to print `$_FILES` you will get all your `image` info

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["save"])) {
// echo "<pre>";print_r($_FILES['pic']);
//then to upload use this
$file_name = $_FILES['pic']['name'];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'];    
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cause, I suggest you to use type submit for submiting form. Please remove this  `<button class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save">Save Changes</button>` with this one `<input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" name="save" id="save">`. Tell me if it does