# Javascript slider value to database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

First off, i'm sure this question has already been answered in one way or another, and I have found a few leads, but since I am kind of lost when it comes to javascript, I can't seem to figure it out. Therefor I require a bit of help.

Here goes:

I have a form that contain a jQuery UI range slider with the min and max values in two different input fields. (Modified version of this: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range)

When I press the 'Set' button I would like the two values from the jQuery range slider to get posted to the php document and then update my database. I am unsure how to do this. The code below isn't doing the trick.

Here is my HTML and Javascript. The PHP document is found further down.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<center>

<header id="layout_header"> </header>

<article id="layout_section_1"> </article>

<article id="layout_section_2">

<form action="foo.php" method="post">

    <input type="text" id="amount" class="input-field" readonly style="width: 60px;">

    <div id="slider-range"></div>

    <input type="text" id="amount2" class="input-field" readonly style="width: 60px;">

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Set">

</form>

</article>


<article id="layout_section_3"> </article>

<article id="layout_section_4"> </article>

<footer id="layout_footer"></footer>

</center>


<!-- Place any per-page javascript here -->

<script>
  $( function() {
        $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
          range: true,
          min: 0,
          max: 100,
          values: [ 20, 80 ],
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ] + "%" );
            $( "#amount2" ).val(ui.values[ 1 ] + "%" );
          }

        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) 
+ "%" );
        $( "#amount2" ).val( "" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) 
+ "%" );
      });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the PHP document:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "db";
$valueone = $_POST['amount'];
$valuetwo = $_POST['amount2'];

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE table SET valueone='$valueone',valuetwo='$valuetwo'";

$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: `WHERE foo = bar` Really?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I see you are missing callbacks for the button. What have you tried? We can help you with your code; people will not write it for you. Do you want it to `$.post()` or do you want it to `.submit()` the form? You need to be more clear. And yes, this specific question, I am sure has been answered before.

Comment: For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694608/submitting-a-form-using-input-type-button

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an AJAX style activity, you can use `$.post()`. This will look like:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#slider-range").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [20, 80],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + "%");
      $("#amount2").val(ui.values[1] + "%");
    }

  });
  $("#amount").val("" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) + "%");
  $("#amount2").val("" + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1) + "%");
  $("form[action='foo.php'] [type='submit']").button();
  $("form[action='foo.php']").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myData = {
      submit: true,
      amount: $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0),
      amount2: $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1)
    };
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), myData, function(result) {
      alert("Values Saved.");
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("Error");
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Test Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/thnfgn0w/

In regards to your PHP, it is susceptible to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You will want to ensure that you protect against this in your code. I would advise something like:

**PHP**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $servername = "server";
    $username = "user";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "db";
    $valueone = (int)$_POST['amount'];
    $valuetwo = (int)$_POST['amount2'];
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE table SET valueone='?',valuetwo='?'"){
        $stmt->bind_param("ii", $valueone, $valuetwo);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```